# iOS 7.1 UISlider setThumbTintColor

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uislider, ios7.1

`[slider setThumbTintColor:color]` has no effect in **iOS 7.1**.

Is there any workaround for setting the thumb color to any random color *(not an image)*?

**EDIT**

The thumb size is *smaller* when using tint color:

- **with** tint: [image]
- **without** tint: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self.slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Thumb.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.slider.thumbTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Can you try like this

Image links :

1x: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjgvn.png
2x: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIMT5.png

Comment: Use the images in you're project file and try.. it will work for sure.. I have tested it.

Comment: That does work miraculously! Weirdest bug I've seen so far in iOS SDK. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try with following code

```
[[UISlider appearance] setThumbTintColor:color];
```

**EDITED :**

First set `UIImage` as `ThumbImage` such like

```
[self.slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Thumb.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Then use following code.

```
self.slider.thumbTintColor = color;
```

Comment: Besides I need to control the color of a specific slider instance.

Comment: @iPatel Apple's documentation says: When customizing slider appearance with images or tint, use one option or the other, but not both. Conflicting settings for track and thumb appearance will be resolved in favor of the most recently set value. For example, setting a new minimum track image for any state clears any custom tint color you may have provided for minimum track images. Similarly, setting the thumb tint color removes any custom thumb images associated with the slider.

Comment: As of iOS 8, what @AnindyaSengupta states is not true.  Make sure that you've set your thumb to render as a template image for it to be tinted:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIView-SW7

Comment: As of iOS 10, I'm seeing the same behavior as described by @AnindyaSengupta.

Comment: If @hélène-martin was ever right about this specific issue (not general guidelines), then not so much now.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46956575/1766265) can be useful in case you want to have both custom thumb image ánd tint color.