# UISlider with custom UIImage set to UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate

Tags: ios, uiimage, uislider

I'm trying to customise the look of a `UISlider` by setting custom images for the thumb, minimumTrack and maximumTrack like so:

```
let sliderThumbImage = UIImage(named: "slider-thumb")
volumeSlider.setThumbImage(sliderThumbImage, forState: .Normal)
let minTrackImage = UIImage(named: "slider-min-track")
volumeSlider.setMinimumTrackImage(minTrackImage, forState: .Normal)
let maxTrackImage = UIImage(named: "slider-max-track")
volumeSlider.setMaximumTrackImage(maxTrackImage, forState: .Normal)
```

This works as expected.

However, I would like to set these images to be template images, by setting their rendering mode to `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate`

The problem is that if I then set the tintColor like this:

```
volumeSlider.thumbTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

then the custom image is removed and the default image is used again.

How can I customise the image, and the tintColor simultaneously?

**Edit:** Docs seem to support the problem I'm having:

> Note that you can only adjust the tint of the default track and thumb
>   images, not custom images. Setting the tint of a part of the slider
>   that has custom images associated with it will remove those images.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISlider.html

Comment: If the docs say you can't do it, then you can't do it. At least not without a hack. You can always create your own custom slider, or pick one from the large variety of controls available through a google search.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the tint color on the UISlider itself, it will change the tint of your custom thumb image.

`volumeSlider.tintColor = .green`

You do however need to create the thumb image with its rendering mode set to alwaysTemplate.  This can be done thru the asset manager or in [code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624153-imagewithrenderingmode).